# read java.security.key stored as object inside a file which is in jar

Tags: jar, public-key

I saved a PublicKey instance in a file using ObjectOutputStream. This file is then stored inside a jar file which is then loaded by JBoss. I'm trying to read this file but it throws me an exception telling that it's not serializable. 
Here is the code :

InputStream input = KeyLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource);
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(input);
Object obj = objectInputStream.readObject();
Key output = (Key) obj;
objectInputStream.close();
return output;

which throws me this exception 
An exception occurred: java.io.NotSerializableException

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about serialization/deserialization from within a jar file, but
without being able to see the rest of your code, I can say a few things:

1. make sure that all of the classes that you are trying to serialize/deserialize implement Serializable.
2. If you can't do number 1, then you might try getting an encoded form of the Key object, such as `key.getEcnoded()`, which would allow you to do input/output using the bytes of the key.

**Edit:**
I'm not really familiar with JBoss, but maybe try using JBossObjectInputStream and JBossObjectOutputStream (org.jboss.serial.io). You will also have to add jboss-serialization.jar to your classpath. see [link](http://www.jboss.org/serialization)

also, I've never done this sort of thing before, but if you think the jar file is complicating things, but you should be able to use some of the classes in the `java.util.jar` package to simplify IO operations with jar files.

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: The Key above is = java.security.Key interface which is serializable. The funny part is that I can load the same file (representing the Key object) within JBoss while the file is not inside JAR, but simply a file on the file system. Also I can read a serialized String object this way. This just don't work for the Key object. Any ideas ?